# AngularFire2 query multiple keys and list results as array

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I have come close to solving this, but needed some assistance in resolving an unexpected issue.

**Project**: Angular 4, Firebase, AngularFire2, TypeScript, Material 2.

I have a list of items. A user can save items as a favourite stored like this, with each item key being stored:

```
{
"kpnnEpz6bSaG64FcLxqgWvG5oMl2": {
    "asgs3100lp23rp9068": true,
    "asgs3100lp2rp48722": true,
    "asgs3100lp57rp885450": true,
    "asgs3100lp8rp195616": true
}
```

}

Then I get the item data for each favourite item key like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
this.favourites = this.getFavs()
}

getFavs(): Observable <any[]> {
    return this.db.list(`/userFavourites/${this.authService.authState.uid}`)
    .map((favKeys: MapItem[]) => favKeys
        .map((favKey: MapItem) => {

            return this.db.object(`/data/baseData/features/${favKey.$key}`)
        }))
    .switchMap((favs) => {

        return Observable.combineLatest(favs);
    });
}

removeAllFavs() {
const item = this.db.object(`/userFavourites/${this.authService.uid}`);
item.remove()
}
```

And then the html is:

```
<md-list>
  <h3 md-subheader>Favourites</h3>
  <md-list-item *ngFor="let favourite of favourites | async">
    {{favourite.$key}} <!--Plus other data-->
  </md-list-item>
</md-list>
```

This seems to work well. However, when I use the removeAllFavs() function, all the items are removed successfully from Firebase, but, the very first item in the list still lingers in the dom and is not removed until the page is reloaded.

So for example, if a user has 10 favorites, 10 favs are loaded successfully in the md-list-item. However, if the user removeAllFavs(), then one favourite is still visible in the browser, until page refresh.

I appreciate your help!

Comment: first, in your DB , all records are empty?  I mean, is the remove() method work as expected? second, try to wrap the ` item.remove() ` with `.then() and .catch() ` , maybe it will provide you more information.

Comment: hey @nisanarz. Yeah, the remove() method works as expected. It removes all the items from the firebase database. But in the UI, all the items disappear except for one item.